# yii2 active record transaction still commit when the validation failed

Tags: mysql, transactions, yii2

I'm using Yii2 active record transaction, but the validation failed in the middle of the codes, it still commit the transaction.
Please advice.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new PoAgen();
    $seq = Sequence::FindOne(['seq_id' => 'INV/AG', 'seq_name' => (int)date('ymd')]);
    if(is_null($seq))
    {
        $_seq = new Sequence();
        $_seq->seq_id = 'INV/AG';
        $_seq->seq_name = (int)date('ymd');
        $_seq->value = 0;
        $_seq->save();
        $model->trx_id = $_seq->seq_id . '/' . $_seq->seq_name . str_pad($_seq->value+1, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    else {
        $seq->value += 1;
        $model->trx_id = $seq->seq_id . '/' . $seq->seq_name . str_pad($seq->value, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $seq->update();
    }

    $model->pot_cong = 0;
    $model->pot_basah_kg = 0;
    $model->pot_tangkai = 0;
    $model->ppn = 0;
    $model->pot_pinjaman = 0;
    $model->pot_panjar = 0;
    $model->ongkos_angkut = 0;
    $model->pot_angkut = 0;
    $model->is_transfer = true;
    $model->buy_date = date('Y-m-d');

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            $model->created_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            $model->created_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $saldo = Saldo::findOne(1); 
            $kas = Kas::findOne(1000); // pembelian agen pks
            $agen = Agen::findOne($model->agen_id);

            if(!$model->is_transfer)
            {
                if($kas->code == 'D')
                {
                    $saldo->balance -= $model->total_bayar;
                }
                else 
                {
                    $saldo->balance += $model->total_bayar;
                }
                $saldo->update();
            }
            $model->save();

            // posting to kasbook
            $kasbook = new KasBook();
            $kasbook->kasbook_id = uniqid();
            $kasbook->kas_date = $model->buy_date;
            $kasbook->ref_trxid = $model->trx_id;
            $kasbook->kas_id = $kas->kas_id;
            $kasbook->code = $kas->code;
            $kasbook->total = $model->total_bayar;
            $kasbook->balance = $saldo->balance;
            $kasbook->received_by = '['. $model->agen_id . '] ' . $agen->agen_name;
            $kasbook->remark = 'Berat Bersih : ' . $model->r_bersih . ', Harga : ' . $model->price;
            $kasbook->vehicle_id = $model->vehicle_id; 
            $kasbook->is_transfer = $model->is_transfer;
            $kasbook->created_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            $kasbook->created_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $kasbook->save();

            if($model->ppn != 0)
            {
                $kb_1 = new KasBook();
                $kb_1->kasbook_id = uniqid();
                $kb_1->kas_date = $model->buy_date;
                $kb_1->ref_trxid = $model->trx_id;
                $kb_1->kas_id = 2000;
                $kb_1->code = 'K';
                $kb_1->total = $model->ppn;
                $kb_1->balance = $saldo->balance;
                $kb_1->remark = 'Ppn Pembelian Agen';
                $kb_1->vehicle_id = $model->vehicle_id;
                $kb_1->is_transfer = true;
                $kb_1->created_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
                $kb_1->created_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $kb_1->save();
            }

            // kurang posting ke purchase order barang
            $transaction->commit();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->trx_id]);
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {                
            $transaction->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }            
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

validation failed in `if($model->ppn !=0) { ... }`
because there is no any primary key in the master table, but the transaction still do commit and the model inserted to database.
Please advice. Thanks before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`save()` method does not throw exceptions but returns boolean so you need to throw it explicitly. Replace every

```
...->save();
```

in try-catch with

```
if (! ...->save()) {
    throw new \yii\db\Exception('Error while saving ... model!');
    // or use general \Exception()
}
```

so now it can be caught.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by :

```
$flag=true;
if($model->ppn != 0)
            {
                $kb_1 = new KasBook();
                $kb_1->kasbook_id = uniqid();
                $kb_1->kas_date = $model->buy_date;
                $kb_1->ref_trxid = $model->trx_id;
                $kb_1->kas_id = 2000;
                $kb_1->code = 'K';
                $kb_1->total = $model->ppn;
                $kb_1->balance = $saldo->balance;
                $kb_1->remark = 'Ppn Pembelian Agen';
                $kb_1->vehicle_id = $model->vehicle_id;
                $kb_1->is_transfer = true;
                $kb_1->created_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
                $kb_1->created_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                if(!$kb_1->save())
                {
                   $flag=false;
                }
            }
            if($flag)
               $transaction->commit();
            else
               $transaction->rollback();
```

Comment: yeah, i have done it since Bizley explained it. Thanks a lot